# C# Excel Word Interop - Identify which range is activating

Tags: c#, excel-interop, word-interop

I am researching on how to identify which range in excel is activating using C# Excel Interop.

I am using office interop to copy paste table from word to excel. After pasting, I notice that some range is selecting / activated (like you copy paste by hand in excel). I want to conduct some further processing in that range before moving to the next paste.

I have googled a lot but no answer relevant. They always show how to activate a range...

Anyone here know how I can do that ?

Thank you so much.

Best Regards,

```
    using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    private void CopyTableFromWordToExcel()
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
        var vungLamViec = xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1];

        object miss = Missing.Value;
        object path = _fileWord;
        object readOnly = true;

        var wordApp = new Word.Application();
        wordApp.Visible = false;

        Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly,
                                       ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                                       ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                                       ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                                       ref miss);
        Excel.Range last = null;
        int lastUsedRow = 0; ;
        int lastUsedColumn = 0;

        foreach (Word.Table table in wordDoc.Tables)
        {
            last = vungLamViec.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
            lastUsedRow = last.Row;
            lastUsedColumn = last.Column;

            vungLamViec.Range["A" + (lastUsedRow + 2).ToString()].EntireRow.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

            Word.Range rng = table.Range;
            rng.Copy();

            vungLamViec.Range["A" + (lastUsedRow + 3).ToString()].Activate();
            
            //there will be a range which is selected / activated by Interop after paste
            vungLamViec.Paste();
        }

        last = vungLamViec.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
        lastUsedRow = last.Row;
        lastUsedColumn = last.Column;

        last = vungLamViec.Range(vungLamViec.Cells[1, 1], vungLamViec.Cells[lastUsedRow, lastUsedColumn]);
        foreach (Excel.Range cell in last)
        {
            if (cell.MergeCells)
            {
                cell.MergeCells = false;
                cell.Style.WrapText = true;
            }
        }

        last.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
        last.EntireRow.AutoFit();

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\Desktop\a.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Missing.Value,
                                Missing.Value, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                                Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true,
                                Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

        xlWorkBook.Close();
        xlApp.Quit();
        ExtensionUtility.releaseObject(xlApp);

        wordDoc.Close();
        wordApp.Quit();
        ExtensionUtility.releaseObject(wordApp);

        ExtensionUtility.ShowMessageBox("Done", "Done");
    }
```